# ASMX Task Scheduler on Godaddy

Tags: asp.net, web-services, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to call my web service (asmx) every hour. The asmx is residing on my shared hosting with Godaddy.

Godaddy use Powershell v1.0. They have an example on their support page: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8970/scheduling-tasks-with-plesk-shared-hosting?pc_split_value=2&countrysite=ca

I am out of my depth here and can't see what they are actually doing in the example. It seems to call downloadstring on an aspx, but I don't understand why you would want to schedule just that?

I copied a powershell script from here: http://poshcode.org/1339

and created my own two line script which calls my asmx function which has no inputs:

```
$page = .\New-WebServiceProxy.ps1 -Url http://www.mysite.co.uk/myasmx.asmx -Anonymous
$page.sendEmail
```

This code is uploaded to the root directory along with the web service.

I tried to run this but putting the script ("email.ps1") doesn't work. I'm not sure if I am using the correct path as its not clear what path I should be using.

**I know the function in the asmx works because I can call it directly in a browser and it works just fine.**

I also tried to use their code almost as is, but replacing this code:

```
-c "(new-object system.net.webclient).downloadstring('http://[domain.tld]\[path]\[file_name]')"
```

with this:

```
-c "(new-object system.net.webclient).uploadstring('http://www.mysite.co.uk\httpdocs\myasmx.asmx/SendEmail', '')"
```

This was kind of out of desperation. I also tried using the path G:\PleskVhosts[domain.tld][path][file_name] which is specific in the PHP example but that doesn't work either.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong or point me in the right direction.

BTW, I am aware of the expireCache hack for those using shared hosting. I've seen the blog https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/ , and this is my backup plan, but I need the call to be regular and don't know how to get the application to start again if it is closed.

Comment: could the person who gave me -1 tell me why? I have set out the problem, explained the attempts I have made myself before asking the question.

Comment: Have found a solution? I need to call asmx files in godaddy.

Comment: @garyson Have you solve your issue, because I've got the same problem, please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Check your backslashes:

Go daddy's example is:

> 'http://www.mysite.co.uk\httpdocs\myasmx.asmx/SendEmail'

Use a slash instead of backslash and the scheduled task will execute normally.